# How do I get the user input to hit a certain method in my mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, function

I have a web form that ask a user for their Id. My overall goal is to be able to take the id and call a function and return a class. The class would return the user name, email, and city.
I am not that far yet. Im still on the first phase.

Is my html code correct? when the button is hit, I want the user input to get pass to the controller?

I want to get the text from the input text in the html. I want to receive the text from the input in my html form. then take that text to the controller which call a user class and display that class

```
<html>
       <div align="center">
        <form id="searchUser" method="post" action="">
            <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
           Enter ID:
             </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="searchButton" id="searchButtong">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </form>
   </div>
   <hr /> 
</html>


Search Controller

 public class SearchController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Search/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string searchUser(string UserId)
    {
        UserId = Request["UserId"];
        return UserId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to make an AJAX request to the action, and have the action return the proper data in JSON.

```
public JsonResult YourActionName(int id)
{
    // Fetch your data from DB, or create the model
    // in whatever way suitable
    var model = new YourModel {
        UserName = "Something"
    };

    // Format the response as JSON
    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: Before getting into AJAX I think it would be better for the OP to familiarize himself with some basic HTTP protocol principles which IMHO he is currently missing.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Agree, after reading through the question again, I realize that OP doesn't mention that he wants to do it through AJAX. Don't know where I got that from, must have been the plain HTML that confused me.

Answer (score 2):

You've already declared the `UserId` variable inside the controller action. You don't need to fetch it from the `Request` again:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]    
    public ActionResult SearchUser(string UserId)
    {
        User user = ... go and fetch the user given the user id 
        // from wherever your users are stored (a database or something)
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

Now you could make your view strongly typed to the `User` class and have a section that will display the results:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.User>"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div align="center">
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("SearchUser", "Search")) { %>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        Enter ID:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="searchButton" id="searchButtong">Search</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <% } %>
    </div>

    <hr /> 

    <% if (Model != null) { %>
        <!-- Display the User results here -->
        <div>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstName) %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.LastName) %>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Now that you have implemented this functionality using standard HTML techniques you could improve it by introducing AJAX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchUser", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" })) { %>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        Enter ID:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="searchButton" id="searchButtong">Search</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <% } %>
    </div>

    <hr /> 

    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- TODO: Adjust with the proper version of jQuery that you are using -->
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then have your controller action return a PartialView:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult SearchUser(string UserId)
{
    User user = ... go and fetch the user given the user id 
    // from wherever your users are stored (a database or something)
    return PartialView(user);
}
```

that you need to define (`~/Views/Search/SearchUser.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<mVCaPPLICATION1.mODELS.uSER>" 
%>
<!-- Display the User results here -->
<div>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstName) %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.LastName) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Is my html code correct? when the button is hit, I want the user input to get pass to the controller?

Comment: No, your HTML is not fine because you haven't specified the controller action to invoke on the form.

Comment: how do i specify the contorller action to invoke on the form? Can you show me in aspx engine?

Comment: By using the Html.BeginForm helper.

Comment: I am using an aspx engine...is there away for you to translate the razor code to aspx engine?

Comment: Sure, that's done, now, I have translated my answer with the WebForms view engine.

Answer (score 1):

Your form tag is the one that determines where the POST will go when the user submits the form. You currently have:

```
<form id="searchUser" method="post" action="">
```

This will direct the POST to the current address.

You can use the MVC form helper to easily change this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    //Your form here
}
```

Or you can manually crank it using the correct URL, or the URL helper.

URL Helper

```
<form id="searchUser" method="post" action="@Url.Action("searchUser", "Search")">
```

Hand Cranked

```
<form id="searchUser" method="post" action="/Search/searchUser/">
```

Comment: is there way to do this in aspx engine?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I assumed Razor. Use `<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>` rather than the ampersat syntax. Pass in the arguments to `BeginForm` to point at your controller and action.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $("#searchButtong").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var usrId=$("#UserId").val();
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("searchUser","search")/"+usrId,function(data){
        //here you may set this to a div in the dom instead of alerting.
        alert(data.UserName);
        alert(data.UserID);
    });
  });
});
```

Assuming you have the action returning a JSON like this

```
public ActionResult searchUser(int id)
{
  UserEntity user=repo.GetUserFromID(id);
  return Json(new { UserName=user.UserName, ID=id},
                                                JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: why am I getting json text? I am only getting the text from the input text in the html. I want to receive the text from the input in my html form. then take that text to the controller which call a user class and display that class

Comment: That is what this code does. It reads the text box value and send to action methdo via getJSON